# Modyifying Ti App xml to include new permission changes for camera and gallery with an earlier sdk

Tags: appcelerator, ios10

I have an App built with Ti SDK 4.0.0 . After Going through the recent release notes for Ti SDK 5.5.0([Release notes for Ti SDK 5.5.0][1]

[1]: https://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/09/ga-release-for-titanium-sdk-5-5-0-appcelerator-cli-5-5-0-appcelerator-studio-4-7-1/) , In order to comply with the new privacy  related changes we need to include few keys in plist in Ti.App XML, for example we need to include NSCameraUsageDescription: If you use the Ti.Media.showCamera API to capture photos and videos for iOS 10.

Now Can I include the same keys in Ti-App XML when distributing the app with Ti SDK 4.0.0 for my App to run in iOS 10 without any problem.Kindly Suggest.

Eventually will migrate the app to the latest SDK.

Comment: as far as I know it will be just ignored on older sdk's

Comment: @RenePot Thanks for the reply.